# django - Many To Many relationship issue

Tags: python, django, database, many-to-many

I am working in django, am planning a database for rides for users.

each **Ride** can have multiple **Users** (passengers) on it, and multiple middle-**destinations** in it.
also, each **Destination** can be in multiple **Rides** and each **User** (passenger) can be on multiple **Rides** (overtime).

Also, for each **Ride** there will be only one **final destination** and only one driver (also a **User**).

**This is my code:**

```
def get_image_path(models.Model):
    return os.path.join('photos',str(instance.id),filename)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User)
    phone_number=models.CharField(max_length=12)
    profile_picture=models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path, black=True, null=True)

class Ride(models.Model):
    driver=models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="r_driver")
    destination=models.ForeignKey(Destination, related_name="r_final_destination")
    leaving_time=models.DateTimeField()
    num_of_spots=models.IntergerField()
    passengers=models.ManyToMany(UserProfile, related_name="r_passengers")
    mid_destinations=models.ManyToMany(Destination, related_name="r_mid_destinations")

class Destination(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**The Issue is** - when a **User** adds a Ride, I want the driver, destination and mid_destinations and the rest of the fields to be set by the **User** (the driver is the **User** adding the Ride), **Except** for the **passengers** field. I want the other **Users** to add themselves to the ride, so when the Ride is created the User (driver) doesn't have to set the passengers.

How do I go about it? and also, any other suggestions about the models?

Comment: Do you mean by, like, using forms or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### About the first part of the question

> The Issue is - when a User adds a Ride, I want the driver, destination
>   and mid_destinations and the rest of the fields to be set by the User
>   (the driver is the User adding the Ride), Except for the passengers
>   field.

#### The django.forms way

You just need a custom Form and handle manually the `driver` field. Something like this:

```
class DriverRideForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ride
        exclude = ('driver', 'passengers', )
```

And then in the `view` where `request.user` is the driver

```
form = DriverRideForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    ride = form.save(commit=False)
    ride.driver = request.user.userprofile
    ride.save()
```

#### The django-rest-framework way

You can but you will probably do not want to exclude the `driver` from the `serializer` fields. This is because usually only one serializer is used per `ViewSet` so you will want to return that field to the consumer of the API.

So you have two options:

- Change the driver field to `read-only` and hook on `perform_create`:

  ```
  class RideSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
          model = Ride
          read_only_fields = ('driver', 'passengers')


  #inside your RideViewSet
  def perform_create(self, serializer): 
       serializer.save(driver=self.request.user.userprofile)
  ```
- Add the `driver` field to the `request.data` before executing `.create` without changing the serializer.

  ```
  #inside your RideViewSet
  def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      request.data['driver'] = self.request.user.userprofile
      return super(RideViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  ```

#### How a user can add himself with read-only `passengers` field?

I would probably do it with a custom endpoint (with `@detail_route`). Something like this:

```
class RideViewSet(...):

    #...

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def attach(self, request, pk=None):
        ride = self.get_object()
        ride.passengers.add(request.user.userprofile)
        return Response(self.get_serializer(ride).data)
```

This way just POST-ing at `url` like `/api/rides/<id>/attach/` will add the logged in `request.user` to the `ride.passengers`.

### About the second part of the question

> any other suggestions about the models?

I think your model structure is fine. I can only think of that in the future you may need more meta data about the relations, so it may be a good moment to be prepared with some `Intermediate Models`, something like:

```
class Ride(models.Model):
    # ...
    passengers=models.ManyToMany(UserProfile, through='RideSeat', related_name="r_passengers")
    mid_destinations=models.ManyToMany(Destination, through='RideMidDestination', related_name="r_mid_destinations")


class RideSeat(models.Model):
    ride = models.ForeignKey(Ride)
    passenger = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    seat_number = models.IntegerField()


class RideMidDestination(models.Model):
    ride = models.ForeignKey(Ride)
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination)
    arrival_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will read about Intermediate Models. about the first part of the question - I am not really sure what a form is. its important to mention that this RESTful API will be only for a mobile app to access it - It doesn't have to have a WEB interface. I guess that a form is for WEB right? basically just looking for a way to let the driver add the Ride (from the app) without having to set the passengers field. they will add themselves. maybe a default value? your thoughts?

Comment: `passengers` is a M2M field, so it do not need any default value, you should be able to create a new `Ride` without providing any information about the passengers. About the forms. Yes they are used for the WEB interface, but can eventually be used to validate your `POST` request and create you a `Ride` instance. How do you build your API? Do you use [`DRF`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Comment: Yes I use DRF, so I think instead of Forms there are Serializers, right? what would be the correct way of getting requests and validating them with DRF?

Comment: Thanks for hour answer.  One question -  i saw you put both driver and passengers as 'read_only'.  The driver i get,  but I want the passengers field to be editable,  because the users are going to add themselfes.  So just remove passengers from read_only?

Comment: It depends on how do you plan to add passengers? Yes the users are going to add themselves but at what endpoint? I would probably use custom endpoint like `/api/rides/<id>/attach/` *(added a simple example)*. This way there will be no need for the `passengers` to be an editable field at a creation level.

Comment: thanks again for your answer! I will use that. one more thing - in the DRF official tutorial there a login/logout in each page in the browsable API, and the only way to create a new user is through the command line. I want the User to be able to  sign up (register) from the app, and also sign in/sign out. Is there any special way of doing that with DRF? do I just create two more views for register and sign in? thanks a lot!

Comment: I think two more views should be enough. There is nothing special in DRF.